# Best way to concatenate multiple strings ignoring blank

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have input from the user for the following family members

Mothersname, Fathersname, Childsname, Sibling1name, Sibling2name

Some of these can be skipped and will be blank. What I want to do is concatenate the non blank entries with a comma but the last one concatenated with the word "and"

e.g. Mary, Bob, Peter and Ellie

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Just loop through, and if one is the last, concatenate it with an `, and` instead of a `, `

Comment: Well it's input from a large form with lots of other inputs. It's not easy to loop through and even determine if each one is the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
names = ['foo1', '', 'foo2', '', 'foo3']
nonblank = names.filter(function (name) { return name.length !== 0 })
out = nonblank.slice(0, nonblank.length - 1).join(', ') + ' and ' + nonblank.pop()
console.log(out); // prints "foo1, foo2 and foo3"
```